# A smudge in his notebook

Tags: mathematics, knowledge

Lothar took his notebook and started scribbling some equations:

\begin{align}
2 + 3&= 412 \\
1+5& = 4321\\
0+4&=4320\\
4320-412&=40\\
4321120-0&=3\\
80-62&=0\\
6+6&=\text{■}
\end{align}

$$\hspace{10mm}\dots$$

Where the $\text{■} $ represents a smudge on the paper.

> Can you restore the missing number? Can you explain these equations?

---

---

**Hint 0:** Trivia reason was mentioned in the comments and answers posted so far.

**Hint 1:**

> The *numbers* here, due to their *nature*, are not necessarily restricted to decimal system notation. For example, valid equation which is consistent with the previous ones: 
> $ A1120 + A110 = 43215 $

**Hint 2:**

> The solution is quite simple and strongly related to the collatz function.

**Hint 3:**

> More valid equations: 
> $41B-C2 = 4511342241113111112121132111211212211112322212 $
> $43810 - 1 =451134224111311111212113211121121221113522121111220 $
> $43810 + 1 =432131412132140 $

Comment: Is this tagged trivia for a reason?

Comment: @thecoder16  Trivia reason ahead **(spoiler/hint):** *Lothar* and his famous unsolved conjecture are related to the construction (values) of numbers in the equations.

Comment: Should I assume all numbers involved in calculating these values are integers, or should i assume nothing? :)

Comment: @DonielF Don't know how much this will help; but it is safe to assume we are dealing with positive integers.

Comment: @NL628 Since you added a bounty I'll wait a bit more. But how long do you think I should wait before adding a hint and/or more equations?

Comment: hmmm one day? it's entirely your decision :)

Comment: @NL628 Hint one was initiated. More are likely to be added in the close future, unless of course someone cracks it in the meantime.

Comment: Aha I got it. But I would prefer someone else to post their complete answer so I can award the bounty.
I think you should give another hint.

Comment: @NL628 2 more hints were added since. Not sure what else to say, and also not give it away.

Comment: Maybe a hint as to why the looong numbers fit the equation

Comment: @NL628 The 3rd hint was meant to take readers attention to the length of the *numbers*. As there's only one property of the collatz function that behaves as the lengths of these *numbers*.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It was my first time doing one of these puzzles so it took me quite a while but I think the answer is :

> $6 + 6 = 7$

And here is how I arrived to this answer:

> Numbers in the equations are constructed by counting the number of even steps between odd steps, in the Collatz evaluation of that number. See [this answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/59042/32666) for more info. 
>
>  For example, the Collatz evaluation for $4$ is : 
> Step 1 $\to4 / 2 = 2$, Started with an EVEN number  
> Step 2 $\to4 / 2 = 1$, Started with an EVEN number  
>
>  We have that $4$ terminates after $2$ EVEN steps.  
>  
> Therefore, when in the equations we see a $2$, it corresponds to a $4$.
>
>
>  Let me explain how $12$ becomes $412$: 
> Step 1 $\to 12 / 2 = 6$  Started with an EVEN number
> Step 2 $\to 6 / 2 = 3$  Started with an EVEN number
> Step 3 $\to (3*3) + 1 = 10$  Started with an ODD number
> Step 4 $\to 10 / 2 = 5$  Started with an EVEN number
> Step 5 $\to (5*3) + 1 = 16$  Started with an ODD number
> Step 6 $\to 16 / 2 = 8$  Started with an EVEN number
> Step 7 $\to 8 / 2 = 4$  Started with an EVEN number
> Step 8 $\to 4 / 2 = 2$  Started with an EVEN number
> Step 9 $\to 2 / 2 = 1$  Started with an EVEN number  
> We use the ODD steps as separators and ignore them:
> We have: $2$ EVEN steps + $1$ EVEN step + $4$ EVEN steps = $214$
>
>  And then reverse that number = $412$
>
>
>  With this, we can now translate the first equation: $2 + 3 = 412$
> Which now actually means: $4 + 8 = 12$

And now we can apply the process in reverse to solve all the equations!

- > $1 + 5 = 4321 \to 2 + 32  = 34$
- > $0 + 4 = 4320 \to 1 + 16  = 17$
- > $4320 - 412 = 40 \to 17- 12 = 5$
- > $4321120 - 0 = 3 \to 9 - 1 = 8$
- > $80 - 62 = 0 \to 85 - 84 = 1$
- > $6 + 6 \to 64 + 64 = 128 → 7$

Comment: I think I understand what you're saying. All the numbers provided in the puzzle are essentially ways of encoding other numbers, by inverting how you would get to 1 from them using the method provided in the Collatz Conjecture.

Comment: That is correct, Congratulations! Also, welcome to the Puzzling Stack Exchange! To address your concern with the third equation: You confused $432$ with $4320$. I proposed an edit to your answer regarding that and the formatting (after it's peer reviewed), if that's okay with you.

Comment: Congratulations! Welcome to Puzzling SE!!

Answer (score 2):

I haven't gotten the answer yet, but here are some things I found out about:

In response to the OP's comment:

> Trivia reason ahead (spoiler/hint): Lothar and his famous unsolved
>   conjecture are related to the construction (values) of numbers in the
>   equations. -Vepir

Here is a little background info:

"Lothar and his famous unsolved conjecture" is the Collatz conjecture, named after Lothar Collatz. It states that given a starting number $n$, and the function $$f(n) =  \begin{cases} n/2 & n\equiv 0\pmod2 \\ 3n+1 & n\equiv 1\pmod2 \end{cases}$$ the application of $f(n)$ will reach $1$ after finite operations. $$$$ In other words, consider the function where "if a number is even, divide it by two" and if a number is odd "multiply it by 3 and add 1." After applying this function multiple times, you will always end up with the number one.

Here's a link for some more [explanations on this conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this brought us any closer to the solution, but here's a table of the numbers mentioned in the equations. $n_0$ is the starting numbers, $N_\text{steps}$ how many "Collatz-iterations" required to reach 1, and $N_\text{odd}$ is how many times an odd number is encountered before 1 is reached ($n_0$ included).

$$
\begin{matrix}
n_0 & N_\text{steps} & N_\text{odd}\\
\hline
2 & 1 & 0\\
3 & 7 & 2\\
4 & 2 & 0\\
5 & 5 & 1\\
6 & 8 & 2\\
40 & 8 & 1\\
62 & 107 & 39\\
80 & 9 & 1\\
412 & 80 & 9\\
4320 & 46 & 13\\
4321 & 170 & 61\\
4321120 & 92 & 27 
\end{matrix}
$$